# one table to another table insert without duplicate record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to copy data from Table T1 to Table T2 with following conditions:
1)data should not be duplicate. 
2)and Column T1-Checkin and T2-checkin must have time difference more than 5 sec.

My existing procedure this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertUserAttendanceLog] @userId varchar(400),@CheckInCheckOutDate datetime,@WorkDate datetime,@InOutMode int,@VerifyMode int, @InsertDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
if 
not exists (select 1 from tblAttendance where CheckInCheckOutDate=@CheckInCheckOutDate and WorkDate=@WorkDate and InOutMode=@InOutMode and VerifyMode=@VerifyMode )
begin
if
not exists (select 1 from tblAttendance where empCode=@userId and convert(date,CheckInCheckOutDate)=convert(date,@CheckInCheckOutDate) and DATEDIFF(second,CheckInCheckOutDate,@CheckInCheckOutDate) <= 3)
begin
 INSERT INTO tblAttendance(EmpCode,CheckInCheckOutDate,WorkDate,InoutMode,VerifyMode,InsertDate)
 VALUES(@userId,@CheckInCheckOutDate,@WorkDate,@InOutMode,@VerifyMode,@InsertDate)
 end
 end
end
```

and i tryed code like this but does not work. geting Dupicate

```
INSERT INTO tblAttendance (EmpCode,CheckInCheckOutDate,WorkDate,InOutMode,VerifyMode,InsertDate,[Status])
SELECT T1.EmpCode,T1.CheckInCheckOutDate,T1.WorkDate,T1.InOutMode,T1.VerifyMode,T1.InsertDate,T1.[Status]
  FROM testAttendanceBulk T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from tblAttendance T2 where T2.CheckInCheckOutDate=T1.CheckInCheckOutDate
 and T2.WorkDate=T1.WorkDate and T2.InOutMode=T1.InOutMode 
 and T2.VerifyMode=T1.VerifyMode and T2.empCode=T1.EmpCode 
 and convert(date,T2.CheckInCheckOutDate)=convert(date,T1.CheckInCheckOutDate) 
 and DATEDIFF(second,T2.CheckInCheckOutDate,T1.CheckInCheckOutDate) <= 5)
```

[it's my table structure](http://rextester.com/JVYQ44588)

Comment: Can you define "does not work"? Are you getting duplicates? Are you getting nothing? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @ Sean Lange geting duplicate thanks

Comment: And don't be scared to add some white space to your queries so they are easier to read. Wall of text sql is awful to work with. Which of your queries is returning duplicates? Both? The first one? The second one? Remember we can't see your screen or read your mind. We can help but you have to provide us with information. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @ Sean Lange first one procedure is working fine but it is taking one by one entry, now i want it to perform like second code in which it is doing copy from one table to another table by a single command thaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can use something like this. Please note my comment on the DATEFIFF predicate, it could be part of the issue you are facing.

```
INSERT INTO tblAttendance 
(
    EmpCode
    , CheckInCheckOutDate
    , WorkDate
    , InOutMode
    , VerifyMode
    , InsertDate
    , [Status]
)
SELECT ab.EmpCode
    , ab.CheckInCheckOutDate
    , ab.WorkDate
    , ab.InOutMode
    , ab.VerifyMode
    , ab.InsertDate
    , ab.[Status]
FROM testAttendanceBulk ab
LEFT JOIN tblAttendance a ON a.CheckInCheckOutDate = ab.CheckInCheckOutDate
    AND a.WorkDate = ab.WorkDate 
    AND a.InOutMode = ab.InOutMode 
    AND isnull(a.VerifyMode, 0) = isnull(ab.VerifyMode, 0) 
    AND a.empCode = ab.EmpCode 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, a.CheckInCheckOutDate) = CONVERT(DATE, ab.CheckInCheckOutDate) 
    AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.CheckInCheckOutDate, ab.CheckInCheckOutDate) <= 5 --do you really want 5 here? Your original query had 3.
WHERE a.empCode IS NULL
```

Comment: OK great. Did you try this query?

Comment: not working  
if i execute message (100 row(s) affected) if i again execute again show (100 row(s) affected) it's fed up me. thanks

Comment: Well perhaps if you would post the table structures and some sample data as I suggested earlier this would be a bit easier for others to help. We are writing queries blind.

Comment: @ Sean Lange sure here is my table structure http://rextester.com/JVYQ44588 thanks

Comment: This is because you have NULL in VerifyMode and the equality check will fail. You can easily wrap them in ISNULL or COALESCE. You should do the same thing for the other columns that allow NULL. See my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145684/discussion-between-goutam-singh-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 0):

In your join, you are checking if the CheckinCheckoutDate is equal, AND if there is a diff of >5 seconds. Try with getting rid of the t1.CheckinCheckoutDate  = T2.CheckinCheckoutDate;

```
 INSERT
      INTO tblAttendance 
           (EmpCode,
            CheckInCheckOutDate,
            WorkDate,
            InOutMode,
            VerifyMode,
            InsertDate,
            [Status])
    SELECT
  DISTINCT T1.EmpCode,
           T1.CheckInCheckOutDate,
           T1.WorkDate,
           T1.InOutMode,
           T1.VerifyMode,
           T1.InsertDate,
           T1.[Status]
      FROM testAttendanceBulk T1
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT T1.EmpCode,
                             T1.CheckInCheckOutDate,
                             T1.WorkDate,
                             T1.InOutMode,
                             T1.VerifyMode,
                             T1.InsertDate,
                             T1.[Status]
                        FROM tblAttendance T2
                       WHERE 1=1 --T2.CheckInCheckOutDate=T1.CheckInCheckOutDate
                         AND T2.WorkDate=T1.WorkDate 
                         AND T2.InOutMode=T1.InOutMode 
                         AND T2.VerifyMode=T1.VerifyMode
                         AND T2.empCode=T1.EmpCode 
                         AND convert(date,T2.CheckInCheckOutDate)=convert(date,T1.CheckInCheckOutDate) 
                         AND DATEDIFF(second,T2.CheckInCheckOutDate,T1.CheckInCheckOutDate) <= 5)
```

Comment: if i execute message (100 row(s) affected) if i again execute again show  (100 row(s) affected)  it's fed up me. thanks

Comment: OK, so from your comment I understand that you do not want to insert duplicates, in that case you can join on the table in which you are inserting. Let me try to update the code.

Comment: Updated my code, you are doing T2.CheckInCheckOutDate=T1.CheckInCheckOutDate AND AND DATEDIFF(second,T2.CheckInCheckOutDate,T1.CheckInCheckOutDate) <= 5). If there is a datediff > 0, they cannot be equal.